# Creating a new filtered stream in KsqlDB with Where clause doesn't work

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

So I have created a stream from a topic. Then I thought I'd create a filtered stream from that using a WHERE clause.

Somewhat like this:

```
CREATE STREAM filtered as select * from original where property = 'value';
```

But then when I select from that stream, I get all entries unfiltered. When I run the query with the WHERE clause on the original stream as a normal select pull query, it works as expected. I can also run the same select/where query on the "filtered" query and get the filtered result, but that wasn't the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that Ksqldb couldn't update/delete the queues related to the query.

Kafka needs to be  configured with `delete.topic.enable=true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM original(k INT KEY, v VARCHAR) WITH (kafka_topic='original', partitions=2, format='json');

ksql> CREATE STREAM foo_filter AS SELECT * FROM original WHERE v='foo';

ksql> INSERT INTO original (k, v) VALUES (1, 'foo');
ksql> INSERT INTO original (k, v) VALUES (2, 'bar');
ksql> INSERT INTO original (k, v) VALUES (3, 'foo');
ksql> INSERT INTO original (k, v) VALUES (4, 'bar');

ksql> select * from foo_filter;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|K                                                                              |V                                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1                                                                              |foo                                                                            |
|3                                                                              |foo                                                                            |
Query Completed
Query terminated
```